# Need better way of making the ball angle in pong game

Tags: java, pong

I'm making a pong clone to practice my coding, and I've become stuck on making the ball be able to change angle when hit by the paddle.

My current implementation has a deltaX and deltaY for the ball, which moves with the game loop to move the ball. The way I have done it is that if you hit the ball while the paddle is moving, the deltaY is increased or decreased depending on the direction of the paddle, but this does not feel natural at all for the game.

Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

Comment: please provide SSCCE(Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)

Comment: Draw it out on paper: what should happen if a ball hits at 90 degrees? What at 45? What at -30? Then write a function that converts this angle.

Comment: How are defining the angle? From the paddle or from a normal to the paddle?

Comment: As I said, I have a delta X and delta Y for the ball, so if deltaX is 3 and deltaY is 1, it moves 3 pixels in x and 1 pixel in Y. I'm not really calculating the angle itself, because I want it to be dynamic and the many angles not just 30/60 or 45s. 

My problem is in a proper way of changing the deltaY so that it feels natural and not as crappy as it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I would do is change the deltaX and deltaY to ballAngle and deltaSpeed. That way you'd be moving from a rectangular coordinates system to a polar one. Due to the nature of the movement of the ball (Goes in a straight line and changes the angle of the line at each impact) this will make your work easier. From now on you'd only have to change ballAngle to update the ball's direction.

However you'll have to update the function that draws the balls for it to move back from polar to rectangular coordinates so you can display it on the screen. A little bit of high-school trigonometry will let you calculate screen position deltas depending on your angle and speed:

```
newPosition = oldPosition + movementVector
```

with:

```
movementVector.x = deltaSpeed*cos(ballAngle)
movementVector.y = deltaSpeed*sin(ballAngle)
```

Of course these equations might need some modification based on relative to what you measure the ball's angle.

Now to modify the ball's angle at each collision with the paddle, you only have to increment or decrement the angle of the ball depending on which part of the paddle it touches, and the math in the drawing function should take care of updating x and y positions realistically.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This sounds like a great idea. Thank you!

Comment: You can calculate the new angle after the collision simply substracting 360 degrees to your actual angle (supposing that the 0º is right direcction). Moreover, you can modify this if your paddle is moving. This is, if in the moment of collision the paddle is moving to right the ball will bound lefter in some degree.

Comment: Subtracting 360 would make it go the other way but very unrealistically. Optimally you'd want to figure out at which angle the ball hit the paddle and mirror it with respect to the paddle's normal. Kind of like a reflection, mirrored with respect to the normal. Now what he wants to do is to skew that angle even more depending on where the paddle is hit, which is standard when it comes to generic brick-busting or pong games.

Comment: Oday, I was originally planning to make it change angle depending on if the paddle was moving, but I like your idea about making the angle change depending on where in the paddle the ball hits. Is this how standard pong works?

Comment: While making the angle depend on paddle speed is interesting, the majority of similar paddle-ball games I've played all do it depending on the part of the paddle being hit.

Comment: If anyone wants to see the outcome of the game, http://zaiber.thepinkbananas.com/ZaiberPong.jar